# ADB and USB drivers for Lava iris atom 2?

Tags: android, drivers

i want to use real android device for my android app development. But i can't able to use this mob for it. I know that i don't have drivers for it. Am using windows 7. Can anyone pls give me a link to download adb and usb drivers for lava iris atom 2?? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally There is no need for USB drivers for connect real device as it is Plug n Play.
Make sure that USB Debugging is on in your phone. and then check your device in Device manager whether it is shown under ADB tab.

and after this if your device demanding USB drivers then follow this path
  YOUR SDK PATH\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Hope It works!!